# remove uncommon lines in two files, but keeping file structure

Tags: python

I have two files, and I want to keep the structure of file 1 (keep lines with ">"), removing the uncommon lines within file1 and file 2. Example:

File 1:

```
>countries
 France
 Italy
>cities
 Rome
```

File 2:

```
France
```

Desired output (removes uncommon lines, keeps ">" lines):

```
>countries
 France 
>cities
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
with open("f1.txt") as file1:
    file1Lines = file1.readlines()
with open("f2.txt") as file2:
    countriesToKeep = file2.readlines()
file1Lines = [i.strip() for i in file1Lines]
countriesToKeep = [i.strip() for i in countriesToKeep]
newFileLines = []
for line in file1Lines:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        newFileLines.append(line)
    elif line in countriesToKeep:
        newFileLines.append(" "+line)

with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in newFileLines:
        output.write(line+"\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would load the countries you would like to keep in a list, and the file you are going through in a list. If the line had the `>` character in it, append it to a new output list or if the line was in `File 2`, then also append it to the output list. Then go through each item in the output list and write it to an output file.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file1:
    file1Lines = file1.readlines()
with open("test2.txt", "r") as file2:
    countriesToKeep = file2.readlines()

newFileLines = []
for line in file1Lines:
    if ">" in line:
        newFileLines.append(line)
    elif line.strip() in countriesToKeep:
        newFileLines.append(line)

with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in newFileLines:
        output.write(line)
```

Comment: use `with open`, to avoid `.close()`. Also `line.startswith(">")` is better?

Comment: hello heinst, it outputs just the ">" lines:  ">countries
>cities"

Comment: @Peaceandlove not on my end...im using python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

My approach was to create a list of lines to be kept from the second file. The list consists of lines from that file that don't start with `>` (not sure if second file is allowed to contain `>`). Then iterate over first file and take only lines that either start with `>` or lines from the keepers list.

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:

    keepers = {line.strip() for line in f2 if not line.startswith('>')}

    lines = [line.strip() for line in f1]

    with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                fout.write(line + '\n')
            elif line in keepers:
                fout.write(' ' + line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner version:

```
print '\n'.join(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('>') or x in map(lambda x: x.strip(), open('file2.txt').readlines()), map(lambda x: x.strip(), open('file1.txt').readlines())))
```